# Как исключить определённые метки в поиске вопросов по другим меткам?

Tags: поддержка, метки, поиск

Я Java-разработчик и заинтересован отвечать на вопросы с меткой [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Однако, под эту метку так же попадают вопросы, помеченные ещё и меткой [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). Как искать вопросы с меткой [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), но исключая вопросы с меткой [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вбейте в поисковую строку:

> [java] -[android]

Получится такая ссылка, можете добавить ее в закладки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+-android

Справочный материал: [Как выполнять поиск?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)